# Angular Material: BreakpointObserver not available from load?

Tags: angular, breakpoints, angular-cdk

While using the Angular `BreakpointObserver` in conjunction with `Angular Material`, I try to use Material Design-spec breakpoints (they're defined in `Breakpoints`, for example `Breakpoints.LandscapePortrait`, `Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait`).

The breakpointObserver works, except for when I freshly load the page. The breakpointObserver is only triggered *after* a change is observed, but considering it's a fresh load, there is no change yet. This means the initial viewport is not yet evaluated against the breakpoints. I've tried using a single `BreakpointObserver.isMatched` in `OnInit`, but this does not seem to take any effect.

I included `BreakpointObserver`, `Breakpoints` and `MediaMatcher` into a shared service, to which I subscribe in all the components that need to "listen" to the breakpoints.

My question is: how can I make sure that the breakpoints are evaluated before the first viewport-change (which may not happen at all, if the user does not resize the window/change device orientation)?

Here's the code of my `shared.service.ts`:

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, Injectable,Input,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, MediaMatcher} from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
    public isCollapsed = false;
    public isOpen = false;
    public isMobileView = false;
    public isTabletView = false;
    private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver;
    @Output() mediaChange = new EventEmitter();
    constructor(breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
        this.breakpointObserver = breakpointObserver;
        // check if the viewport matches Material Design-spec handset displays
        this.breakpointObserver.observe([
          Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait
        ]).subscribe(result => {
          if (result.matches) {
            this.isMobileView = true;
            this.isTabletView = false;
            this.isOpen = false;
            this.isCollapsed = false;
          }
          else {
            this.isMobileView = false;
            this.isOpen = true;
            this.isCollapsed = false;
          }
          this.mediaChanged();
        });
        // check if the viewport matches Material Design-spec tablet displays
        this.breakpointObserver.observe([
          Breakpoints.TabletPortrait
        ]).subscribe(result => {
          if (result.matches) {
            this.isTabletView = true;
            this.isMobileView = false;
            this.isOpen = true;
            this.isCollapsed = true;
          }
          else {
            if(!this.isMobileView){
                this.isOpen = true;
            }
            this.isTabletView = false;
            this.isCollapsed = false;
          }
          this.mediaChanged();
        });
    }
    mediaChanged() {
        this.mediaChange.emit({
          "isMobileView" : this.isMobileView,
          "isTabletView" : this.isTabletView,
          "isCollapsed" : this.isCollapsed,
          "isOpen" : this.isOpen
      });
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        // MY ATTEMPT
        // Running the same checks as the observer, but this time on init(?)
        // does not seem to take any effect
        if(this.breakpointObserver.isMatched([
          Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait
        ])){
            this.isMobileView = true;
            this.isTabletView = false;
            this.isOpen = false;
            this.isCollapsed = false;
        }
        if(this.breakpointObserver.isMatched([
          Breakpoints.TabletPortrait
        ])){
            this.isTabletView = true;
            this.isMobileView = false;
            this.isOpen = true;
            this.isCollapsed = true;
        }
        this.mediaChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem and found this related issue: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13852 ... so far no answers :'(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set a local variable to false and change it depending on the value in the subscription.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-menu',
  templateUrl: './main-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-menu.component.css']
})
export class MainMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  isHandset = false;

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
      .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
        if (state.matches) {
          this.isHandset = true;
        } else {
          this.isHandset = false;
        }
      });
  }

}
```

Template code:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="isHandset ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="isHandset ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="isHandset === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>timplaw-dotcom</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Reference: https://alligator.io/angular/breakpoints-angular-cdk/

Comment: I think this is the answer. Within Angular, I think subscribing and awaiting changes is the way to go. As I learned more about Angular through the course of developing, this makes much more sense now than would probably have done back when I asked the question. Thanks!